# Upload a 10 GB file File into SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint

We have requirement to upload a large File, possibly 10 GB , or up to 50 GB file size into SharePoint Online.

As per the new limit [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/restrictions-and-limitations-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa) , Maximum file upload size is increased upto 250 GB.

Can we upload a large File of 10GB or 50 GB into SharePoint online using SPFX File Upload or SharePoint REST API services?

If So, Please guide me the right approach, Do we need to split the file into chunks and upload? if so, What is the maximum File Chunk size?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach to have sucesfull with this requirement is use a CSOM Library: At Microsoft Docs, titled [Upload large files sample SharePoint Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint), contains useful examples that provide you to Upload large files, using C# PRogramming. Bellow contains an code example that you may use as a Console Application:

```
public static void UploadDocumentContent(ClientContext ctx, string libraryName, string filePath)
{
  Web web = ctx.Web;

  FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();

  // The next line of code causes an exception to be thrown for files larger than 2 MB.
  newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
  newFile.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);

  // Get instances to the given library.
  List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);

  // Add file to the library.
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
  ctx.Load(uploadFile);
  ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

At Console Application Main method, you'll call the created method above:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 using(ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/business"))
 {
  ctx.Credentials =  = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username@tenantdomain", "add secure password object");
  UploadDocumentContent(ctx, "Documents", @"C:\FileFolder\FileName.ext")
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response . I am afraid whether we can use CSOM with .NET as we have other customization requirements also like share the files to others. So we decided to use SPFX front end for custom forms and SharePoint using as backend

Comment: @Faisal, you can create an Web Service with a responsability to do this File Upload with CSOM Library and consumes this new custom Web Service in your SPFx application.

Comment: Sure, I will try this option. Thanks for guiding the right approach

Comment: @Faisal, as this approach makes sense, please, it's possible to do a check for this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use [Core.LargeFileUpload](https://github.com/pnp/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.LargeFileUpload) to upload large files.You can take following link as sample
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint

Comment: Thanks for the response. We have some additional requirement as the user need to upload files, share etc. We are going with SPFX as front end .